# Firebird Database Stored Procedure in SSRS - not loading the stored procedure

Tags: reporting-services, load, firebird, procedure

I have a stored procedure running in Firebird Database. Now I try to use this stored procedure to build a report in the SSRS 2012 (SSDT) Report Designer.

After I connect to the dataset, and when I choose the Query Type as 'Stored Procedure', and type the name of  my stored procedure, and then go to the Query Designer, and click ! (F5),   I get the following error:

```
TITLE: Microsoft SQL Server Report Designer
------------------------------

An error occurred while executing the query.
ERROR [HY000] [ODBC Firebird Driver][Firebird]Dynamic SQL Error
SQL error code = -104
Token unknown - line 1, column 1 [sproc name] 

------------------------------
ADDITIONAL INFORMATION:

ERROR [HY000] [ODBC Firebird Driver][Firebird]Dynamic SQL Error
SQL error code = -104
Token unknown - line 1, column 1 [sproc name] (OdbcFb)

------------------------------
BUTTONS:

OK
------------------------------
```

Any idea on how to resolve this? If its a T-SQL stored procedure, then it will be no issue; in this case, Firebird database connects to the SSRS via a 32-bit System ODBC connection.

When I proceed and click ok for everything, I get this error (after I exit the Query Designer), in the Dataset Properties tab:

> Could not update a list of fields for the query. Verify that you can
>   connect to the data source and that your query syntax is correct.

The ODBC connection between SSRS and Firebird works fine. In fact I am able to run many queries as ad-hoc ones, but when I use the queries as stored procedure, then this issue pops up.

Any suggestion on how to handle Firebird stored procedures in SSRS will be greatly appreciated.

Comment: It's telling you that your query syntax is not correct.  So, you don't think you should share the sql statement !!!

Comment: the stored procedure executes correctly in the Firebird database - so its not about the syntax;  any idea on how to run Firebird PSQL Stored Procedure in Microsoft SSRS ?

Comment: Is it a selectable or an executable stored procedure? And is that the full error message? A token unknown usually also shows the token the parser fails on.

Comment: I have posted the full message here  (StackOverFlow does not allow me to post the exact error message):  https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/sqlserver/en-US/e57d9aed-6eb9-4c52-827b-3319449f03fc/firebird-database-stored-procedure-in-ssrs-ssrs-not-loading-the-stored-procedure?forum=sqlreportingservices

Comment: It is a stored procedure that SELECTs data; for the matter any Firebird PSQL stored procedure that I add into SSRS  Report Designer throws the same error.

Comment: Does it literally say `[sproc name]`? The `[` and `]` are SQL Server style quotes. Firebird uses `"`. Note that you might be better of using `SELECT * FROM theStoredProcedure` (selectable) or `EXECUTE PROCEDURE theStoredPrcodure` (executable) instead.

Comment: I have not changed anything in the message posted - except for replacing the name of my stored procedure with sproc;

Comment: Ok; Can you provide me the exact syntaxes to run a stored procedure
in Firebird; can we use SELECT * FROM StoredProcedure ?  If so how to mention parameters?  Something like this - 2 parameters with 2 question marks:

SELECT * FROM StoredProcedure  ? ?

Comment: `select from storedprocedure(?, ?)`

Comment: Hi Mark - I have posted a new question (I need to get this new one fixed before I come to this SSRS loading issue):   http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32181998/firebird-in-ibexpert-throws-errors-while-accessing-some-stored-procedure

Comment: Hi Mark, I found a temporary solution to the IBExpert access issue for now; returning back to this question:  when I run SELECT FROM StoredProcedure (?,?) - I get the same error;   however when I run EXECUTE PROCEDURE  StoredProcedure (?, ?) - I do NOT get an error - and I am able to see the output correctly!!  but I just see the FIRST row only - when there needs to be several hundreds; I tried changing the parameters many times - all I see is the first of the n rows of the supposed to resultset;  (of course the whole operation was done using query type as text - and running SELECT/EXECUTE )

Comment: ie  n rows when I run the sproc in Firebird/IBExpert; only the first row is retreived by SSRS

Comment: `EXECUTE PROCEDURE` only produces a single row, that is why you shouldn't use it for a selectable stored procedure. You might want to try to execute it as a normal query (so using `SELECT * FROM storedprocedure(...)`) and not telling SSRS it is a stored procedure.

Comment: Thanks very much Mark , it works now!!  I now used SELECT * FROM sproc; in your earlier post you did not put the    * (asterix symbol); so I thought that it the exact syntax in Firebird PSQL; now I used with the * and am able to sort it you; Great, thx!!!

Comment: ie:  SELECT * FROM storedprocedure (?,?)  is correct;       but     SELECT   FROM storedprocedure (?,?) is incorrect;

Comment: Sorry about that, I hadn't noticed my typo.