# Firebird in IBExpert throws errors while accessing some stored procedure

Tags: parsing, format, firebird, access-violation, ibexpert

I am completely new to Firebird; I have been given a Firebird 2.5 database (by our client)  -   XYZ.fdb

I have registered this XYZ.fdb database in IB Expert.

I am able to run successfully some views and stored procedures. However for some other views or stored procedure, I get the following error:

can't format message 13:896 - message file C:Windows\firebird.msg not found;
invalid request BLR at offset 623; function LTRIM is not defined; module name or entrypoint could not be found; Error while parsing procedure   XXXXXXX  (stored_procedure name) ;

### Error Message:

Access violation at address 00DCA0E5 in module 'IBExpert.exe'. Read of address 00000000.

It was working fine last week; I had tried to restart the system, and install Firebird and IB expert over and over again; I get the above error for a few stored procedures and views, but the other views and stored procedures are working fine.

Since I did not have this issue last week, and in between I reinstalled Firebird and IB Expert a couple of times, I think it has some configuration or registration issue.

Can you provide me a step by step approach to fix this issue - such that I can access all database objects in the Firebird DB using IB Expert ?

Comment: `ltrim` is a UDF, not a builtin function. You need to ensure that the UDF library is accessible and allowed by the firebird configuration. The access violation most likely is a bug in IBExpert.

Comment: Verify that the file  `ib_udf.dll` is located in the folder `..\Firebird\Firebird_2_5\UDF`

Comment: I have ib_udf.dll - in the UDF folder - in both the 32-bit client (in Program Files (x86) ) as well as the 64-bit client (in Program Files)

Comment: When I open IBExpert, I get this:                             IBExpert currently uses IBExpert.stg (C:Users\....\AppData\Roaming\HK-Software\IBExpert\IBExpert.stg) as a main storage for its data.

This way is obsolete now and will not be supported in the future.

Instead we strongly recommend to setup IBExpert  User Database in Options|Environment Options| User Database.

Comment: `IBExpert.stg` is  the database where `IBExpert` keep the data by default. You can set own  firebird database instead. But this is not a reason for your problem. 
Check `firebird.conf` file for this line : `#UdfAccess = Restrict UDF` - must have # simbol in front.

Comment: Hi Val, Thanks for the information.  I checked this line in the firebird.conf file - and I indeed find :  #UdfAccess = Restrict UDF;     by the way I don't know what I did - I am able to run successfully the stored procedures and views that I couldn't earlier today!!; but if this issue pops up again, I will post the update

Comment: If you have not, in the mean time, see my other question related to Firebird/IBExpert (particularly the comments part):  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32153793/firebird-database-stored-procedure-in-ssrs-not-loading-the-stored-procedure

Comment: Hi Val, This error is back now!! I did not have it for over a day, but suddenly, I see this again.  I will explain the situation:  I have a 3rd party application - ABC; when I install ABC, Firebird 32 bit client is also installed along with a database called XYZ.fdb (all a part of ABC installation).This ABC application develops reports using the Firebird 32bit client, and the XYZ.fdb database;The reports developed by the ABC application is fine; but when I run the same Views and Stored Procedures that the ABC application uses,in IBExpert(with the XYZ.fdb) or SSRS-I get this error sporadically.

Comment: ie the database objects (of XYZ.fdb) work well with the ABC application; but when I run the same objects  via IB Expert or SSRS - ocassionally i get this error; we don't know what solves this issue, but the error suddenly vanishes, and we are able to run the objects successfully in SSRS and IB Expert; suddenly we get this error back!! in all this period the ABC application uses these same objects and runs reports successfully!!

Answer (score 0):

The resulting error might be created by an access violation from IBExpert, but the reason is definitely a missing UDF library, for example a .dll file called `rfunc.dll` or `freeadhocudf.dll` or whatever it is called.

To find the name of the missing .dll, check the UDFs used in the database by clicking on UDF folder in IBExpert database registration.

Comment: Can you elaborate this explanation ? I am facing this error sporadically. I did not find this yesterday, but now see this error yet again!!

Comment: Can you provide me step by step instructions?